# get a category tree array from a csv file

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, csv

I've got a csv with 3 fields : Code, parent, label like that :

```
code;parent;label
cata;;"Category A"
level1;cata;level1
level1_1;level1;"level 1 - 1"
level1_2;level1;"level 1 - 2"
level1_3;level1;"level 1 - 3"
level1_4;level1;"level 1 - 4"
level2;cata;level2
level2_1;level2;"level 2 - 1"
level2_2;level2;"level 2 - 2"
level2_3;level2;"level 2 - 3"
level2_4;level2;"level 2 - 4"
catb;;"Category B"
blevel1;catb;level1
blevel1_1;level1;"level 1 - 1"
blevel1_2;level1;"level 1 - 2"
blevel1_3;level1;"level 1 - 3"
blevel1_4;level1;"level 1 - 4"
blevel2;catb;level2
blevel2_1;level2;"level 2 - 1"
blevel2_2;level2;"level 2 - 2"
blevel2_3;level2;"level 2 - 3"
blevel2_4;level2;"level 2 - 4"
```

I'm tryng to make an Array like First level is "Cat A", second level is "level1" and third level is "level 1 - 1" with all 3 fields (code,parent,label) at the last level.

```
-cata
--level1
---level1_1
---level1_2
---level1_3
---level1_4
--level2
---level2_1
---level2_2
---level2_3
---level2_4
-catb
--blevel1
---blevel1_1
---blevel1_2
---blevel1_3
---blevel1_4
--blevel2
---blevel2_1
---blevel2_2
---blevel2_3
---blevel2_4
```

I try several things, but a little bit "stuck".
I can read my csv and make an array without problem. but my concern is "after" to create the result array.

this is my "fisrt attempt"

```
$file = 'imports/test-cat.csv';
$all_rows = array();
$header = null;

$f = fopen($file, "r");
$size = filesize($file) + 1;
while ($row = fgetcsv($f, $size, ";")) {
 if ($header === null) {
    $header = $row;
    continue;
}
  $all_rows[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}
fclose($f);
```

If someone can tell me in what direction I have to go

Thanks

Comment: `I try several things, but a little bit "stuck".` Then show some of that code, so someone can help out.

Comment: Can you us show an example of the output you want ?

Comment: I edit my first topic with the result I want.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm good now (perhaps not the best way but it's working)

```
//variables
$file = 'test.csv';
$all_rows = [];
$new = [];
$tofind = [];
$header = null;

//function
function createTree(&$list, $parent){
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($parent as $k=>$l){
        if(isset($list[$l['code']])){
            $l['children'] = createTree($list, $list[$l['code']]);
        }
        $tree[] = $l;
    } 
    return $tree;
}


//parsing CSV
$f = fopen($file, "r");
$size = filesize($file) + 1;
while ($row = fgetcsv($f, $size, ";")) {
 if ($header === null) {
    $header = $row;
    continue;
}
  $all_rows[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}


foreach ($all_rows as $a){
    $new[$a['parent']][] = $a;
}
//Get all root parent id
$keys = array_keys(array_column($all_rows, 'parent'), '');

foreach ($keys as $key){
    $tofind[]= $all_rows[$key];
}

//Tree
$tree = createTree($new, $tofind);
```

If you have some sugggestion I take it :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach:

```
function getTree($by_parent, $parent = '')
{
    $ret = [];
    foreach ($by_parent[$parent] as $row) {
        if (isset($by_parent[$row['code']])) {
            $ret[$row['code']] = getTree($by_parent, $row['code']);
        } else {
            $ret[$row['code']] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}

$file = 'imports/test-cat.csv';
$all_rows = array();
$header = null;

$f = fopen($file, "r");
$size = filesize($file) + 1;
while ($row = fgetcsv($f, $size, ";")) {
    if ($header === null) {
        $header = $row;
        continue;
    }
  $all_rows[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}

$by_parent = [];
foreach ($all_rows as $row) {
    $by_parent[$row['parent']][] = $row;
}


$tree = getTree($by_parent);
```

Now I am tempted to do another try without any recurrence or $by_parent. If input file is sorted, then it should be perfectly doable to do it sequentially.

Comment: is there any way to get the first parent? i mean it only got the code of category, but i want to get all array is like

[
  'parent_id' => 0,
 'children' => array(...)

...
]